# Collection of unrelated Models in Backbone?

Tags: backbone.js, model-view-controller

I am creating a single page app that lets users filter for data upon two criteria (Skills and Location). This data is to be populated from two separate web services.

There is a model for each service to consume the data using REST style requests.

[image]

I want to use both bits of data in this one view. From my understanding a collection can hold multiple instances of one type of Model e.g. "Movie"

```
     var Movies = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Movie,
        initialize: function() {
            console.log("");
            console.log("Movie Collection initialize");
            console.log(this);
            console.log(this.length);
            console.log(this.models);
        }
    });

    var movie1 = new Movie({
        "title": "Bag It",
        "averageUserRating": 4.6,
        "yearReleased": 2010,
        "mpaaRating": "R"
    });

    var movie2 = new Movie({
        "title": "Lost Boy: The Next Chapter",
        "averageUserRating": 4.6,
        "yearReleased": 2009,
        "mpaaRating": "PG-13"
    });
```

However I am trying to implement the pattern below, where the collection has two Models. Is this an anti pattern for Backbone. How should this be tackled?

```
    define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/locationsModel',
    'models/skillsModel'
], function (_, Backbone, Location, Skills)
{
    'use strict';

    var FiltersCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        // The filters collection requires these two models that will provide data to the filters view
        location: new Location(),
        skills: new Skills(),

        initialize: function() {
            //Do stuff
    }
    });

    return new FiltersCollection();
});
```

Comment: separate collections for each type of model; a single view that displays from each collection appropriately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't advise on what is best for you because I can't visualise your data properly based on the info provided. But if you observe the collection constructor in the Backbone source:

```
if (options.model) this.model = options.model;
```

Then in _prepareModel:

```
var model = new this.model(attrs, options);
```

And we knew that "model" is a function anyway, and a function can return what you want. So providing your two different data sources have some attribute that can identify them you can do something like this:

```js
var SkillModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    sayMyName: function() {
        return 'I am a skill model and I am skilled at ' + this.get('name');
    }
});

var LocationModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
   sayMyName: function() {
        return 'I am a location model and I am relaxing in ' + this.get('name');
    } 
});

function FilterModel(attrs, options) {
    if (attrs.type === 'skill') {
        return new SkillModel(attrs, options);
    } else if (attrs.type === 'location') {
        return new LocationModel(attrs, options);
    }
}

var FilterCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: FilterModel
});
    
var filteredCollection = new FilterCollection([{
    type: 'skill',
    name: 'carpentry'
}, {
    type: 'location',
    name: 'India'
}, {
    type: 'skill',
    name: 'plumbing'
}]);

var outputEl = document.querySelector('#output');

filteredCollection.each(function(model) {
    outputEl.innerHTML += '<p>' + model.sayMyName() + '<p>';
});
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js"></script>

<div id="output"></div>
```